# Need an algebraic formula for this algorithmic problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

I'm not sure if there is a given term for this problem but I'm trying to find the number of iterations required to complete this type of pattern:

Consider two patterns/lists: `[a,b,c]`  &  `[0,1]`

The entire pattern would be `a0 b1 c0 a1 b0 c1` and the number of iterations would be 6.

I wrote a perl script to calculate several of these patterns:

3 vs. 2:

```
    1:      1 1
    2:      2 2
    3:      3 1
    4:      1 2
    5:      2 1
    6:      3 2
```

4 vs. 5:

```
    1:      1 1
    2:      2 2
    3:      3 3
    4:      4 4
    5:      1 5
    6:      2 1
    7:      3 2
    8:      4 3
    9:      1 4
    10:     2 5
    11:     3 1
    12:     4 2
    13:     1 3
    14:     2 4
    15:     3 5
    16:     4 1
    17:     1 2
    18:     2 3
    19:     3 4
    20:     4 5
```

6 vs. 4:

```
    1:      1 1
    2:      2 2
    3:      3 3
    4:      4 4
    5:      5 1
    6:      6 2
    7:      1 3
    8:      2 4
    9:      3 1
    10:     4 2
    11:     5 3
    12:     6 4
```

12 vs. 9:

```
    1:      1 1
    2:      2 2
    3:      3 3
    4:      4 4
    5:      5 5
    6:      6 6
    7:      7 7
    8:      8 8
    9:      9 9
    10:     10 1
    11:     11 2
    12:     12 3
    13:     1 4
    14:     2 5
    15:     3 6
    16:     4 7
    17:     5 8
    18:     6 9
    19:     7 1
    20:     8 2
    21:     9 3
    22:     10 4
    23:     11 5
    24:     12 6
    25:     1 7
    26:     2 8
    27:     3 9
    28:     4 1
    29:     5 2
    30:     6 3
    31:     7 4
    32:     8 5
    33:     9 6
    34:     10 7
    35:     11 8
    36:     12 9
```

Is there a term for this type of "algorithm"?  How can I algebraically solve for the number of iterations without going through each one at a time?

Can someone help me derive a formula?

Comment: If given 'x vs. y', looks like it's:
$$\frac{x * y}{\text{gcd}\left( x , y \right)}$$?

Comment: please expand... gcd = greated common denomination?

Comment: gcd($x , y$) typically means 'Greatest Common Divisor of $x$ and $y$'

Comment: wouldn't that resolve to 1 if x & y were 2 & 3, respectively?

Comment: gcd(2,3) = 1

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: ok i see the difference now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two inputs $a$ and $b$ the running time is the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$, which is typically notated ${\rm lcm}(a,b)$.

The least common multiple $m$ is the smallest number you can find so that there are two other numbers $h$ and $k$ which together satisfy

$$ah = bk = m$$

In your case, you are taking two lists $(1,\dots,a)$ and $(1,\dots,b)$ and repeating them side by side, until the lengths of the outputs coincide (I presume that this is exactly what your Perl script does). When you have done this, you will have written the first sequence out $h$ times and the second sequence $k$ times, for a total of $m={\rm lcm}(a,b)$ iterations.

An easy way to calculate the least common multiple is first to calculate the greatest common divisor (using [Euclid's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)) and then use the relationship

$${\rm lcm}(a,b) = \frac{ab}{{\rm gcd}(a,b)}$$

More information about the least common multiple available on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple).

Comment: Haha, totally forgot that what I wrote down WAS the LCM :P

Comment: that looks good so far using 4 vs 6

Comment: thats it... thanks a lot!

Comment: im using this to write poly-rhythmic music... helps me figure out how many times the drummer needs to repeat a 4/4 bar!

Comment: @Nicolas sorry, didn't see your comment when I posted this - props to you!

Comment: is there a name for this pattern?